# Animate nav's margin-top when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Cookie bar fixed at the top of my website. 
When the **Close** icon is clicked, the bar fades.

Because of the position of the div, I'm also forcing my `.nav` element down by 64px.

**Question:** Is it possible that when I click the `Close` icon that the `margin-top` on my `.nav` is gradually reduced to `0` too? With a similar animation speed? I'm unsure how to achieve this

Here is my Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ox19egn4/

**Also**, what is the best way to set my `.nav` to `margin-top:0px` permanently after the user has seen the Cookie bar notice?
Should I just set it to 0 in my CSS but temporarily set to 64px in JS?

```js
/**
 *  
 * JQUERY EU COOKIE LAW POPUPS
 * version 1.0.0
 * 
 * Code on Github:
 * https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-eu-cookie-law-popup
 * 
 * To see a live demo, go to:
 * http://www.wimagguc.com/2015/04/jquery-eu-cookie-law-popup/
 * 
 * by Richard Dancsi
 * http://www.wimagguc.com/
 * 
 */

(function($) {

// for ie9 doesn't support debug console >>>
if (!window.console) window.console = {};
if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function () { };
// ^^^

var EuCookieLawPopup = (function() {

 var _self = this;

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // PARAMETERS (MODIFY THIS PART) //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 _self.params = {
  cookiePolicyUrl : '/cookie-privacy-policy/',
  popupPosition : 'bottom',
  colorStyle : 'default',
  compactStyle : false,
  popupTitle : 'This site uses cookies to store information on your computer',
  popupText : '',
  buttonContinueTitle : 'Learn more',
  buttonLearnmoreTitle : 'Learn&nbsp;more',
  buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow : true,
  agreementExpiresInDays : 30,
  autoAcceptCookiePolicy : true,
  htmlMarkup : null
 };

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // VARIABLES USED BY THE FUNCTION (DON'T MODIFY THIS PART) ////////////////////////////////////
 _self.vars = {
  INITIALISED : false,
  HTML_MARKUP : null,
  COOKIE_NAME : 'EU_COOKIE_LAW_CONSENT'
 };

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS FOR MANIPULATING DATA ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 // Overwrite default parameters if any of those is present
 var parseParameters = function(object, markup, settings) {

  if (object) {
   var className = $(object).attr('class') ? $(object).attr('class') : '';
   if (className.indexOf('eupopup-top') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'top';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-fixedtop') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'fixedtop';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-bottomright') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'bottomright';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-bottomleft') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'bottomleft';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-bottom') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'bottom';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-block') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'block';
   }
   if (className.indexOf('eupopup-color-default') > -1) {
    _self.params.colorStyle = 'default';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-color-inverse') > -1) {
    _self.params.colorStyle = 'inverse';
   }
   if (className.indexOf('eupopup-style-compact') > -1) {
    _self.params.compactStyle = true;
   }
  }

  if (markup) {
   _self.params.htmlMarkup = markup;
  }

  if (settings) {
   if (typeof settings.cookiePolicyUrl !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.cookiePolicyUrl = settings.cookiePolicyUrl;
   }
   if (typeof settings.popupPosition !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.popupPosition = settings.popupPosition;
   }
   if (typeof settings.colorStyle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.colorStyle = settings.colorStyle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.popupTitle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.popupTitle = settings.popupTitle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.popupText !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.popupText = settings.popupText;
   }
   if (typeof settings.buttonContinueTitle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.buttonContinueTitle = settings.buttonContinueTitle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.buttonLearnmoreTitle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.buttonLearnmoreTitle = settings.buttonLearnmoreTitle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow = settings.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow;
   }
   if (typeof settings.agreementExpiresInDays !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.agreementExpiresInDays = settings.agreementExpiresInDays;
   }
   if (typeof settings.autoAcceptCookiePolicy !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.autoAcceptCookiePolicy = settings.autoAcceptCookiePolicy;
   }
   if (typeof settings.htmlMarkup !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.htmlMarkup = settings.htmlMarkup;
   }
  }

 };

 var createHtmlMarkup = function() {

  if (_self.params.htmlMarkup) {
   return _self.params.htmlMarkup;
  }

  var html = 
   '<div class="eupopup-container' + 
       ' eupopup-container-' + _self.params.popupPosition + 
       (_self.params.compactStyle ? ' eupopup-style-compact' : '') + 
    ' eupopup-color-' + _self.params.colorStyle + '">' +
    '<div class="eupopup-head">' + _self.params.popupTitle + '</div>' +
    '<div class="eupopup-body">' + _self.params.popupText + '</div>' +
    '<div class="eupopup-buttons">' +
      '<a href="#" class="eupopup-button eupopup-button_1">' + _self.params.buttonContinueTitle + '</a>' +
      '<a href="' + _self.params.cookiePolicyUrl + '"' +
      (_self.params.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow ? ' target=_blank ' : '') +
     ' class="eupopup-button eupopup-button_2">' + _self.params.buttonLearnmoreTitle + '</a>' +
      '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<a href="#" class="eupopup-closebutton"><img src="/images/icons/svg/close.svg"></a>' +
   '</div>';

  return html;
 };

 // Storing the consent in a cookie
 var setUserAcceptsCookies = function(consent) {
  var d = new Date();
  var expiresInDays = _self.params.agreementExpiresInDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  d.setTime( d.getTime() + expiresInDays );
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = _self.vars.COOKIE_NAME + '=' + consent + "; " + expires + ";path=/";

  $(document).trigger("user_cookie_consent_changed", {'consent' : consent});
 };

 // Let's see if we have a consent cookie already
 var userAlreadyAcceptedCookies = function() {
  var userAcceptedCookies = false;
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
   var c = cookies[i].trim();
   if (c.indexOf(_self.vars.COOKIE_NAME) == 0) {
    userAcceptedCookies = c.substring(_self.vars.COOKIE_NAME.length + 1, c.length);
   }
  }

  return userAcceptedCookies;
 };
 
 var hideContainer = function() {
  // $('.eupopup-container').slideUp(200);
  $('.eupopup-container').animate({
   opacity: 0,
   height: 0
  }, 200, function() {
   $('.eupopup-container').hide(0);
  });
 };

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 var publicfunc = {

  // INITIALIZE EU COOKIE LAW POPUP /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  init : function(settings) {

   parseParameters(
    $(".eupopup").first(),
    $(".eupopup-markup").html(),
    settings);

   // No need to display this if user already accepted the policy
   if (userAlreadyAcceptedCookies()) {
    return;
   }

   // We should initialise only once
   if (_self.vars.INITIALISED) {
    return;
   }
   _self.vars.INITIALISED = true;

   // Markup and event listeners >>>
   _self.vars.HTML_MARKUP = createHtmlMarkup();

   if ($('.eupopup-block').length > 0) {
    $('.eupopup-block').append(_self.vars.HTML_MARKUP);
   } else {
    $('BODY').append(_self.vars.HTML_MARKUP);
   }

   $('.eupopup-button_1').click(function() {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
    hideContainer();
    return false;
   });
   $('.eupopup-closebutton').click(function() {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
    hideContainer();
    return false;
   });
   // ^^^ Markup and event listeners

   // Ready to start!
   $('.eupopup-container').show();

   // In case it's alright to just display the message once 
   if (_self.params.autoAcceptCookiePolicy) {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
   }

  }

 };

 return publicfunc;
});

$(document).ready( function() {
 if ($(".eupopup").length > 0) {
  (new EuCookieLawPopup()).init({
   'info' : 'YOU_CAN_ADD_MORE_SETTINGS_HERE',
   'popupTitle' : 'This site uses cookies to store information on your computer',
   'popupText' : '',
   'buttonLearnmoreTitle' : ''
  });
 }
});

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.eupopup-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 190;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: block;
}

.nav {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  margin-top: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="nav">
    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x300">
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, in your function `hideContainer`, you can add:

```
$('.nav').animate({
  'margin-top': 0
}, 200);
```

or you could have directly set the CSS property of `.nav`:

```
top: 64px
```

and animate this property in your javascript code.

Comment: Hi @ekqnp thank you for this. I've updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/ox19egn4/7/ That's a fantastic answer. Many thanks!!!!

Comment: I have spotted that after I close it and navigate the site, I still have `margin-top:64px` applied to `.nav`. How do I set it to `0` permanently after closing the bar?

Comment: ^ That message for @ekqnp :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk glad I helped !

Answer (score 2):

I'm recommend to use `css` of course. Something like this:

```js
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.cookie').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('.content').addClass('nocookie');  
  });
});
```

```css
.cookie {
  text-align:center;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

.close {
  font-size:80%;
  color:inherit;
}

.content {
  transform:translateY(20px);
  transition:all .3s ease;
}

.content.nocookie {
  transform:translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cookie">Cookie Cookie Cookie Cookie Cookie Cookie Cookie Cookie Cookie Cookie <a href="#" class="close">close</a></div>
<div class="content">Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant!!
I have to keep the code I'm using right now but perhaps I can merge the two sets of code together :-)